# Easy SMTP:Test email process is failed

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

Hey I've been working with wordpress for quite some time now. This is the first time I'm going to use contact forms with emails. From what I understood is that before you implement emailing in your form you have to test your smtp. I downloaded Easy SMTP. I set my SMTP host name to smtp.gmail.com, port is 465. My encryption is "Use SSL Encryption", my authentication is Yes. Then I inputted my gmail username and password. But when I send a test mail, it always replies Test email process is failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to change sendmail path on php.ini file .
Like this:"sendmail -t -i"(Replace with :
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t" )

try to this on php.ini file.and check it out.

Comment: I'm doing this on a test site.

Comment: first check your php.ini file on your server.and all requirement value.